# How can I setup SSH Tunneling with AT&T on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, connection, isp

It has been suggested to me to try using SSH Tunneling to try and improve my internet connection and make it more reliable in my apartment.  I am running OS X Snow Leopard and the internet provided from the apartment complex is with AT&T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need to have a SSH server to tunnel through.  But, once you've got that there are several other questions out there that explain how to set up tunneling:

- [Set up a home VPN to allow web browsing from remote network](https://superuser.com/questions/46702/set-up-a-home-vpn-to-allow-web-browsing-from-remote-network)